# c++ inheritance data access confusion

Tags: c++, inheritance

I seem to have a basic bit of confusion about data access in a subclass.
I have a parent class that contains a vector.
I set up a child subclass that inherits from the parent class,
but I cannot access the vector in the subclass?

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class parentClass
{
 public:
  std::vector<T> teaList;
 };

template <typename T>
class childClass: public parentClass<T>
{
public:
  void echostuff(){cout <<"size "<<teaList.size()<<endl;}
};

using namespace std;
main()
{
  childClass<int> foo;
  foo.echostuff();
}
```

how would I access the list in the subclass?

Comment: You must use `this->teaList.size()`. See the duplicate questions for more details.

Comment: Or `parentClass<T>::teaList.size()`.

Comment: Or add `using parentClass<T>::teaList;` and use `teaList.size()` as it is.